# Extends Service e Implements Activity en la misma clase || Android

Tags: java, android, app, activity

Estoy intentando hacer una app Android que oculte tanto la barra de notificaciones como la barra de acciones(volver al inicio, etc), por tanto había pensado en crear un servicio que oculte la barra de acciones ya que con la de notificaciones no tengo problema pero al crearlo me veo obligado a tener que utilizar tanto `Service` como `Activity`, esto me da el error en el `Activity`:

> Interface expected here

mi código:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;

import android.view.View;

public class FirstService extends Service implements Activity{


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        View view = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);


        this.stopSelf();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

}
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar que salga la barra de notificaciones y el menú de acciones puedes cambiar directamente el tema de tu app en el `AndroidManifest.xml` para obligar que aparezca en pantalla completa:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

---

O cambiar el `parent` de tu tema en `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</style>
```

Y aplicarlo de la siguiente manera en el xml de tu `Activity`:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

---

O usar este código en el `onCreate` de tu Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: Con eso consigo ocultar la barra de notificaciones, pero la de acciones sigue apareciendo

Comment: He añadido otra solución @JuanmaM . Pruébalo